# Definite article or No article?

Tags: articles, definite-article

I just came across the following sentence;

> Many Americans love to watch reruns of *the* I Love Lucy show.

and think that ***the*** in there is extraneous. What rule applies to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely not extraneous. In fact, I'd say it was required.

Interestingly enough, if we remove the word *show*, then we would omit the article, too:

> Many Americans love to watch reruns of *I Love Lucy*.

but we could not say:

> Many Americans love to watch reruns of show. `(INCORRECT)`

unless the word was pluralized:

> Many Americans love to watch reruns of shows.

The [EF website](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/definite-article/) lists 15 reasons when we use a definite article, but I'm having trouble figuring out which of those rules applies to this sentence. However, the CUNY School of Law has a [webpage](http://www.law.cuny.edu/legal-writing/students/multilingual/grammar/articles.html) about the definite article with a rule that seems to apply:

> In general, the article THE is used **when a noun has a specific reference to something unique**.

In this case, the noun is *show*, and it's referring to a particular (i.e. a unique) show.

On the EF website, that rule is expressed as:

> Use *the* in sentences or clauses where you define or identify a particular person or object.

I think those are essentially two ways of trying to say the same thing, but the wording of the former maps a little better to the sentence in this question. An example on the law school website is:

- the 2001 CUNY budget

which aligns pretty closely with:

- the *I Love Lucy* show